# How to resize an image in flavor of InputStream before saving it in a blob field mysql

Tags: java, image-resizing

I have a web page that allows user to upload images and save them into a blob field of a MySQL DB. I need to resize those images, and I would like to know what the steps are.

Now, I get the image this way:

```
InputStream content = request.getPart("immagine").getInputStream();
```

What should I do to resize the image? Should I turn the `InputStream` into a `BufferedImage`, then resize it and then turn it into an `InputStream` again before saving it into the DB?

Comment: Have you tried that? It seems like a fairly sensible thing to do... you're not going to be able to resize it as long as it's a raw InputStream, so using javax.image.ImageIO to read it into a BufferedImage, resize, and then write it out again seems like a good idea. So try it.

Comment: No, i still havent tried it. I asked to know if there was a better and faster way than mine.
that's why i asked before doing it :)

Answer (score 2):

We had similar requirement, to crop and re-size image. we used **imgscalr** library for this.

```
BufferedImage img = //Convert you input image to BufferedImage, we used ImageIO.read for this.
BufferedImage scaledImg = Scalr.resize(img, Scalr.Method.ULTRA_QUALITY, Scalr.Mode.AUTOMATIC,  400, 300); //400,300 was the size we expected
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: link for imgscalr --> http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/